# Use KVO for NSTextFields that are bound together

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, nstextfield

I'm having trouble getting KVO working with text fields that are bound together in a Cocoa app. I have gotten this to work when setting strings in NSTextFields with buttons but it is not working with bindings. As always, any help from Stack Overflow would be greatly appreciated.

Purpose of my code is to:

- bind several text fields together
- when a number is input in one field, have the other fields automatically update
- observe the changes in the text fields

Here's my code for MainClass which is an NSObject subclass:

```
#import "MainClass.h"

@interface MainClass ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *fieldA;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *fieldB;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *fieldC;

@property double numA, numB, numC;

@end

@implementation MainClass

static int MainClassKVOContext = 0;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self.fieldA addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"numA" options:0 context:&MainClassKVOContext];
    [self.fieldB addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"numB" options:0 context:&MainClassKVOContext];
    [self.fieldC addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"numC" options:0 context:&MainClassKVOContext];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context != &MainClassKVOContext) {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
        return;
    }

    if (object == self.fieldA) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"numA"]) {
            NSLog(@"fieldA length = %ld", [_fieldA.stringValue length]);
        }
    }

    if (object == self.fieldB) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"numB"]) {
            NSLog(@"fieldB length = %ld", [_fieldB.stringValue length]);
        }
    }

    if (object == self.fieldC) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"numC"]) {
            NSLog(@"fieldC length = %ld", [_fieldC.stringValue length]);
        }
    }
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingNumB {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"numA"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingNumC {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"numA"];
}

- (void)setNumB:(double)theNumB {
    [self setNumA:theNumB * 1000];
}

- (double)numB {
    return [self numA] / 1000;
}

- (void)setNumC:(double)theNumC {
    [self setNumA:theNumC * 1000000];
}

- (double)numC {
    return [self numA] / 1000000;
}

- (void)setNilValueForKey:(NSString*)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"numA"]) return [self setNumA: 0];
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"numB"]) return [self setNumB: 0];
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"numC"]) return [self setNumC: 0];
    [super setNilValueForKey:key];
}

@end
```

And here is the binding for one of the text fields:
[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Key-Value Observing on NSTextFields

In your `-awakeFromNib` method's implementation, you've written

```
[self.fieldA addObserver:self 
              forKeyPath:@"numA" 
                 options:0 
                 context:&MainClassKVOContext];
```

This doesn't do what you're hoping it will: `self.fieldA` is not *[key-value coding compliant](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-BAJEAIEE)* for the key `numA`: if you try sending `-valueForKey:` or `-setValue:forKey:` with the key `@"numA"` to `self.fieldA`, you'll get the following exceptions:

> **[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numA.**

and

> **[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numA.**

[As a result](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html), the `NSTextField` instances are not *key-value **observing** compliant* for `@"numA"`, either: the first requirement to be KVO-compliant for some key is to be KVC-compliant for that key.

It is, however, KVO-compliant for, among other things, `stringValue`.  This allows you to do [what I described earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130613/controltextdidchange-not-working-for-setting-string-of-nstextfield/13132980#13132980).

**Note**: None of this is altered by the way that you've set up bindings in Interface Builder.  More on that later.

### The Trouble With Key-Value Observing on NSTextField's stringValue

Observing an `NSTextField`'s value for `@"stringValue"` works when `-setStringValue:` gets called on the `NSTextField`.  This is a result of the internals of KVO.

#### A Brief Trip Into KVO Internals

When you begin observing an key-value observing an object for the first time, the object's class is changed--its `isa` pointer is changed.  You can see this happening by overriding `-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`

```
- (void)addObserver:(NSObject *)observer 
         forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
            options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options 
            context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"%p, %@", self->isa, NSStringFromClass(self->isa));
    [super addObserver:observer 
            forKeyPath:keyPath 
               options:options 
               context:context];
    NSLog(@"%p, %@", self->isa, NSStringFromClass(self->isa));
}
```

In general, the name of the class changes from `Object` to `NSKVONotifying_Object`.

If we had called `-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` on an instance of `Object` with with the key path `@"property"`--a key for which instances of `Object` are KVC-compliant--when next we call `-setProperty:` on our instance of `Object` (in fact, now an instance of `NSKVONotifying_Object`), the following messages will be sent to the object

1. `-willChangeValueForKey:` passing `@"property"`
2. `-setProperty:` passing `@"property"`
3. `-didChangeValueForKey:` passing `@"property"`

Breaking within any of these methods reveal that they're called from the undocumented function `_NSSetObjectValueAndNotify`.

The relevance of all of this is that the method `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` is called on the observer that we added to our instance of `Object` for the key path `@"property"` **from** `-didChangeValueForKey:`.  Here's the top of the stack trace:

```
-[Observer observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]
NSKeyValueNotifyObserver ()
NSKeyValueDidChange ()
-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] ()
```

#### How does this relate to `NSTextField` and `@"stringValue"`?

In your [previous setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130613/controltextdidchange-not-working-for-setting-string-of-nstextfield#comment17920328_13132980), you were adding an observer to your text field on `-awakeFromNib`.  This meant that your text field was already an instance of `NSKVONotifying_NSTextField`.

You would then press one or another button which in turn would call `-setStringValue` on your text field.  You were able to observe this change because--as an instance of `NSKVONotifying_NSTextField`--your text field, upon receiving `setStringValue:value` actually received

1. `willChangeValueForKey:@"stringValue"`
2. `setStringValue:value`
3. `didChangeValueForKey:@"stringValue"`

As above, from within `didChangeValueForKey:@"stringValue"`, all the objects which are observing the text field's value for `@"stringValue"` are notified that the value for this key has changed in their own implementations of `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`.  In particular, this is true for the the object which you added as an observer for the text field in `-awakeFromNib`.

In summary, you were able to observe the change in the text field's value for `@"stringValue"` because you added yourself as an observer of the text field for that key and **because `-setStringValue` was called on the text field**.

#### So What's The Problem?

So far under the guise of discussing "The Trouble With Key-Value Observing on NSTextFields" we've only actually made sense of the opening sentence

> Observing an `NSTextField`'s value for `@"stringValue"` works when `-setStringValue:` gets called on the `NSTextField`.

And that sounds great!  So what's the problem?

The problem is that `-setStringValue:` does not get called on the text field as the user is typing into it OR even after the user has ended editing (by tabbing out of the text field, for example).  (Furthermore, `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:` are not called manually.  If they were, our KVO would work; but it doesn't.)  This means that while our KVO on `@"stringValue"` works when `-setStringValue:` is called on the text field, it does *NOT* work when the user herself enters text.

**TL;DR**: KVO on the `@"stringValue"` of an `NSTextField` isn't good enough since it doesn't work for user input.

### Binding An NSTextField's Value To A String

Let's try using bindings.

#### Initial Setup

Create an example project with a separate window controller (I've used the creative name `WindowController`) complete with XIB.  ([Here's the project I'm starting from on GitHub.](https://github.com/natechan/WindowedAppTemplate))  In `WindowController.m` added a property `stringA` in a class extension:

```
@interface WindowController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSString *stringA;
@end
```

In Interface Builder, create a text field and open the Bindings Inspector:

[image: Bindings Inspector]

Under the "Value" header, expand the "Value" item:

[image: NSControl Value Binding]

The pop-up button next to the "Bind to" checkbox presently has "Shared User Defaults Controller" selected.  We want to bind the text field's value to our `WindowController` instance., so select "File's Owner" instead.  When this happens, the "Controller Key" field will be emptied and the "Model Key Path" field will be changed to "self".

[image: Binding NSControl Value to File's Owner]

We want to bind this text field's value to our `WindowController` instance's property `stringA` so change the "Model Key Path" to `self.stringA`:

[image: Binding NSTextField's Value to File's Owner's property stringA]

At this point, we are done.  ([Progress so far on GitHub.](https://github.com/natechan/TextFieldSyncDemo/tree/85b4decc78899a39df5977e77efab180c2b09dd8))  We have successfully bound the text field's value to our `WindowController`'s property `stringA`.

#### Testing It Out

If we set `stringA` to some value in -init, that value will show up in the text field when the window loads:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"WindowController"];
    if (self) {
        self.stringA = @"hello world";
    }
    return self;
}
```

[image: Showing 'hello world' in Text Field]

And already, we have set up bindings in the other direction as well; upon ending editing in the text field, the our window controller's property `stringA` is set.  We can check this by overriding it's setter:

```
- (void)setStringA:(NSString *)stringA
{
    NSLog(@"%s: stringA: <<%@>> => <<%@>>", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, _stringA, stringA);
    _stringA = stringA;
}
```

#### Reply Hazy, Try Again

After typing some text into the text field and pressing tab, we'll see printed out

```
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<(null)>> => <<some text>>
```

This looks great.  Why haven't we been talking about this all along???  There's a bit of a hitch here: the pesky **pressing tab** thing.  Binding a text field's value to a string does not set the string value until editing has ended in the text field.

#### A New Hope

However, there is still hope!  The [Cocoa Binding Documentation for `NSTextField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTextField.html) states that one binding option available for an `NSTextField` is `NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption`.  And lo and behold, there is a checkbox corresponding to this very option in the Bindings Inspector for NSTextField's value.  Go ahead and check that box.

[image: NSTextField's value binding continuously updates stringA]

With this change in place, as we type things in, the update to the window controller's `stringA` property is continuously logged out:

```
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<(null)>> => <<t>>
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<t>> => <<th>>
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<th>> => <<thi>>
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<thi>> => <<thin>>
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<thin>> => <<thing>>
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<thing>> => <<things>>
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<things>> => <<things >>
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<things >> => <<things i>>
-[WindowController setStringA:]: stringA: <<things i>> => <<things in>>
```

Finally, we're continuously updating the window controller's string from the text field.  The rest is easy.  As a quick proof of concept, add a couple more text fields to the window, bind them to stringA and set them to update continuously.  You at this point have three synchronized `NSTextField`s!  [Here's the project with three synchronized text fields.](https://github.com/natechan/TextFieldSyncDemo/commit/14d615b1e4bdf8a2d7b74b005592dbf75c912b80)

### The Rest of the Way

You're wanting to setup three textfields that display numbers that have some relationship to each other.  Since we're dealing with numbers now, we'll remove the property `stringA` from `WindowController` and replace it with `numberA`, `numberB` and `numberC`:

```
@interface WindowController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *numberA;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *numberB;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *numberC;
@end
```

Next we'll bind the first text field to numberA on File's Owner, the second to numberB, and so on.  Finally we just need to add a property which is the quantity which is being represented in these different ways.  Let's call that value `quantity`.

```
@interface WindowController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *quantity;

@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *numberA;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *numberB;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *numberC;
@end
```

We'll need the constant conversion factors to transform from the units of `quantity` to the units of `numberA` and so forth, so add

```
static float convertToA = 1000.0f;
static float convertToB = 573.0f;
static float convertToC = 720.0f;
```

(Of course, use the numbers that are relevant to your situation.)  With this much, we can implement the accessors for each of the numbers:

```
- (NSNumber *)numberA
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.quantity.floatValue * convertToA];
}

- (void)setNumberA:(NSNumber *)numberA
{
    self.quantity = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:numberA.floatValue * 1.0f/convertToA];
}

- (NSNumber *)numberB
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.quantity.floatValue * convertToB];
}

- (void)setNumberB:(NSNumber *)numberB
{
    self.quantity = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:numberB.floatValue * 1.0f/convertToB];
}

- (NSNumber *)numberC
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.quantity.floatValue * convertToC];
}

- (void)setNumberC:(NSNumber *)numberC
{
    self.quantity = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:numberC.floatValue * 1.0f/convertToC];
}
```

All of the different number accessors are now just indirect mechanisms for accessing `quantity`, and are perfect for bindings.  There is only one additional thing that remains to be done: we need to make sure that observers repoll all of the numbers whenever `quantity` is changed:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingNumberA
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"quantity"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingNumberB
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"quantity"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingNumberC
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"quantity"];
}
```

Now, whenever you type into one of the textfields, the others are updated accordingly.  [Here's the final version of the project on GitHub](https://github.com/natechan/TextFieldSyncDemo/commit/c5b6a9564166652b46060a336336bd3ea1ea16a1).

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer I've ever seen on SO, and I've been here a long time.  +1

Comment: @nate Wow! This is the best answer ever on Stack Overflow. Great job!

Comment: @nate So in your final version where is the KVO?

Comment: You can't do it with KVO unfortunately. With bindings, you're able to get continuous updates, which is crucial for what you're trying to accomplish. If you KVO on @"self.cell.objectValue" you'll get a KVO notification whenever editing ends in the text field, but NOT continuously.

Comment: @NateChandler Can you help out with my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484053/kvo-causes-loop-if-observers-to-other-objects-are-not-removed . I'm trying to find a way to change the conversion factor based on which text field has user input.

Comment: Wow what an extensive answer!

Comment: The most comprehensive answer I've seen too!